# Manual creation of nodes and ng-model

Tags: angularjs

In more attempts to DRY bootstrap and AngularJS, I'm attempting to create a form and children while maintaining the `ng-model` relationships.  I'm getting the correct HTML output, but something isn't connecting correctly with the model relationships, and the model isn't being updated:

#### Vanilla HTML

```
<form role="form" ng-model="customer">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="customer.name" />
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Simplified (goal) HTML

```
<div abs-form ng-model="customer">
  <input id="name" label="Full Name" placeholder="i.e. Joe Smith"/>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.customer = {};
}
```

#### abs-form Directive

```
.directive('absForm', function($compile){
var input = $('<input />'),
    label = $('<label />');
    group = $('<div class="form-group"></div>'),
    formElements = [];
return {
  restrict : 'EA',
  replace : true,
  transclude : false,
  scope : {
    ngModel : '=',
    label : "@"
  },
  compile : function(tElement, tAttrs){
    var children = tElement.children();

    var tplElement = angular.element('<form role="form" ng-model="'+ tAttrs.ngModel +'" />');

    // Clear the HTML from our element
    tElement.html('');

    // Loop through each child in the template node and create
    // a new input, cloning attributes
    angular.forEach(children, function(child){
      var newInput = input.clone(),
          newLabel = label.clone(),
          newGroup = group.clone(),
          $child = $(child),
          attributes = child.attributes;

      // Add the "for" attribute and the label text
      newLabel.attr('for', $child.attr('id'));
      newLabel.text($child.attr('label'));

      // Add the class to the input
      newInput.addClass('form-control');
      newInput.attr('ng-model', tAttrs.ngModel + "." + $child.attr('id'));

      // Copy the attributes from the original node to the new one
      $.each(attributes, function(index, prop){
        newInput.attr(prop.name, prop.value);
      })

      // Store the form elements for use in link() later
      formElements.push(newLabel, newInput)

      // Some reason passing in the formElements botches the appending
      newGroup.append([newLabel, newInput]);

      // Append the group to the element
      tplElement.append(newGroup)
    })
    //$('input', tplElement).wrap('<span>')

    // finally, replace it with our tplElement
    tElement.replaceWith(tplElement);

  }
}
})
```

This is the output of the directive above, like I said, the HTML is fine (as far as I can tell), but there's no connection of the model:

```
<form role="form" ng-model="customer" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="customer.name" id="name" label="Full Name" placeholder="i.e. Joe Smith">
    </div>
</form>
```

Some of the questions I've found with similar scenarios (and similar ways to solve)

- [Changing ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578554/angularjs-is-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-ngmodel-attribute-on-directive?rq=1)
- [Adding ngModel to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405790/adding-ngmodel-to-input-with-a-directive)

The second question was the best scenario, but I can't seem to get my new inputs to contribute to the "customer" model.  I'm thinking there's more to it than just adding or changing the `ng-model` attribute on the node, but something Angular is doing to register the connection...?

Comment: Not sure what benefit `ng-model` does on form tag...but form defintiely needs `name` if you want it published to scope and use validation [ngForm Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngForm) I always create forms with arbitrary names non related to the `ng-model` object used for inputs. Then use the form name for validation such as `ng-disabled="formName.$invalid"` on a submit button

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in my pocket as it doesn't solve the problem, but is good practice. The `ng-model` on the form tag is to have a place for the child nodes to know what model they're attaching to, parsing the name of the model from the compile function, and appending `.[inputId]`, i.e. `customer.name`.

Comment: never had to use it since `ng-model` on inputs automatically register with scope object as per docs, they also get bound into the formName object. Docs for `ngModel` only talk about input/textarea/select etc not the form itself

Comment: following up just becaue I'm curious. Is it possible that's been an assumption that you've had about registering it on form tag? If there's easier ways to expose things I'm all open...but haven't figured out how it;s used. And there's no documentation for it on form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your directive is that it introduces an isolate scope which does not include the original model name. The scope variable `customer` is henceforth known by the name `ngModel` within the directive's scope.

I updated the code to get rid of the jQuery dependency but basically it still does the same things.

See this fiddle: [manual creation of nodes and ng-model](http://jsfiddle.net/GVG3m/1)

Comment: That looks solid, scope is a tricky beast sometimes. I'll test out more when I'm home and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: That'll do it! Such a minor change, thanks a million!